# Does travelling with Danse after Blind Betrayal impact Brotherhood of Steel reputation?

Tags: fallout-4

Once you've completed the Blind Betrayal quest by saving Paladin Danse he is exiled from the Brotherhood, but he is still available as a companion. Under these conditions, asking Paladin Danse to accompany you will prompt a warning that while he is travelling with you both of you will be considered enemies of the Brotherhood. Any Brotherhood of Steel members that you come across will be kill-on-sight.

Now, obviously, fast-travelling to the Prydwen and stopping by Maxson's quarters to say hello would cause some real issues. But what about the random-spawned Knights and Vertibirds that you'll encounter in the wasteland?

Are there any long-term ramifications to killing randomly-spawned Brotherhood members while you are with Paladin Danse? Will killing these enemies hurt your relationship with the Brotherhood once you're no longer travelling with Danse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played the game long enough to know that after the quest Blind Betrayal, you can attack any unnamed brotherhood of steel member with no ramifications. If you complete the quest and then side with any other faction that causes the Prydwen to be destroyed he will ignore you. So, you can do what you want with Danse as long as you don't go on the airship.

Answer (score 3):

You can kill as many randomly spawned brotherhood members as you want without consequence, I stacked up about 80k caps selling their loot and probably hundreds of kills later they are still friendly

Answer (score 0):

If you are aligned with the brotherhood then killing anyone from the brotherhood will hurt your reputation with them. Eventually they will turn hostile, how long it takes depends on how many quests you have done for them.

At a certain point in the game you have to do a quest to make something and you can choose which faction to do it with, if you choose the railroad or the institute Danse will become hostile towards you and can no longer be taken as a companion.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is right; I've killed quite a few unnamed Brotherhood members now and haven't turned permanently hostile yet. Once I get off work today I think I'll make it a point to go on a Brotherhood killing spree for science.

Comment: Does Danse really turn hostile if you support the Railroad *after* completing Blind Betrayal? That's surprising.